# Android EditText not showing keyboard

Tags: android

I have just started programming on Android and have completed the MyFirstApp tutorial:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

The app runs, however when I touch the text field, the soft keyboard does not popup.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    >
</EditText>
```

I have tried adding:

```
  <requestFocus />
```

but that makes no difference.

I have added this to the mainifest, but that also makes no difference:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"
```

Surely this kind of functionality is already built in and I don't have to create a custom function (method) to achieve this ? - I would have expected the tutorial to at least mention that the keyboard won't popup using the provided code, as I have spent the last 3 hours trying to figure out what was wrong with my code !

### EDIT

I am working on the latest 4.42 and have added the clearFocus() however that makes no difference:

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    
    editText.clearFocus();
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: are you using the emulator?

Comment: Are you using `TabHost` within your code?

Comment: I am using a real Android Tablet for testing, sorry but what is TabHost ?? - I am a complete beginner on Android.

Comment: `TabHost` is a `FrameLayout` for adding a tab bar in your app. You might find more info here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html I was just asking because I had the same issue which turned to be a bug of `TabHost`, but if you're not using it, obviously it's not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this appears to be a bug in version 18 (4.4), when I compile for version 14, the keyboard appears.

#### This works:

```
android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

#### This does not:

```
android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you said which version you was working on (2.3/4.4 etc) but assuming it is 2.1-2.3 then this link may help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7743066/2978914

It states that you should clear the focus of the Edit text itself.

Direct quote from link above:

> OK, This might be a late response, but it worked.
>
> I have met this problem on android 2.1 and 2.3.x(not tested on other
>   versions of SDKs).
>
> I noticed a strange thing that when my click on the EditText was
>   unable to open the keyboard, I pressed the BACK button to show an
>   alert dialog and then I canceled(closed) it, and clicked the EditText
>   again, now the keyboard was brought to life again.
>
> From that I can conclude that the keyboard will always show for the
>   EditText if the EditText does not previously own focus(showing an
>   alert dialog over the EditText view will make the EditText to lose
>   focus).
>
> so call the function below on your EditText when it is brought to
>   front:
>
> **mEditText.clearFocus();** or
>
> **parentViewThatContainsEditTextView.clearFocus();**

Comment: Thanks, I am using 4.2, I also tried the suggestion but it did not resolve the problem.

Comment: no problem, in that case check out this post which has a specific fix for 4.2.x im not able to test myself. do you happen to be using fragments?
http://stackoverflow.com/q/16389380/2978914

Comment: Sorry, but I am a complete beginner so I'm not really sure about fragments, but I have looked thru the tutorial again (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html ) and can't see any reference to fragments.

Comment: what IDE are you using to write code? eclipse or android studio? if you use one of the default templates from android studio they may be using a fragmented design (when you create a new project), here's android fragments documentations http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Thanks, I am using eclipse, latest version downloaded this morning.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's still struggling with the keyboard which is not opening when clicking on EditText please **check to have `android:inputType` set.**

Without it, the keyboard won't open.